# Nesting enums in Java

Tags: java, enums

I want to nest some enums. The object i'm representing are Flags, with a type, and a value. There are a discrete number of types, and each type has a distinct set of possible values.

So if Type A can have values 1, 2 or 3, and Type B can have values 4,5,6, I'd like to be able to do things like:

```
Flag f = Flag.A.1;

f.getType() - returns "A"

f.getValue() - returns "1"

Flag f2 = Flag.A.4; -- Syntax error.
```

I'm driving myself crazy trying to nest enums within enums - is what i'm trying possible - do I need to ditch enums altogether and handcraft a static class with static members?

My best effort so far is:

```
public class Flag {

    enum A extends Flag {
        ONE("ONE"),
        TWO("TWO"),
        THREE("THREE");

        private A(String value) {
            Flag.type = "A";
            Flag.value = value;
        }
    }

        private static String type;
        private static String value;
}
```

But if I do:

```
Flag f = Flag.A.ONE;
```

The types are incompatible.

Comment: You cannot use `1` or `4` as identifier for your enum values. Care to embed more source code?

Comment: an `enum` cannot extend a `class`.

Comment: And to be a bit more verbose: An `enum` automatically extends `Enum<E>` (where `E` is the `enum` type) and Java only has single inheritance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot have a number as an enum. It has to be an identifier.

You can do this

```
interface Flag {
    String getType();
    int getValue();
    enum A implements Flag{
        one, two, three;
        String getType() { return getClass().getSimpleName(); }
        int getvalue() { return ordinal()+1; }
    }
    enum B implements Flag{
        four, five, six;
        String getType() { return getClass().getSimpleName(); }
        int getvalue() { return ordinal()+4; }
    }
}

Flag f = Flag.A.one;
```

However a simpler option may be

```
enum Flag {
    A1, A2, A3, B4, B5, B6;
    public String getType() { return name().substring(0,1); }
    public int getValue() { return name().charAt(1) - '0'; }
}

Flag f = Flag.A1;
```

Comment: I think it'd be better to use a public final class with a private constructor instead of an interface for Flag.

Comment: @deinocheirus  How would use a `public final class` in the first example where there is multiple subclasses?  BTW an `enum` is a public final class with private constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Nesting enums is not possible. But enums can implement interfaces. Why not have `A` and `B` as two different enums that both implement a `TypedEnum` interface with `getType()` and `getValue()` methods?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand enums, they are kind of singletons. It means enum X {A,B} has two singleton instances A,B. If you had nested enum A { P, Q }, how you can say if X.A is X.A.P or X.A.Q ? I wish I was able to say it more simply.

Use static class.