# Should I use a nested enum?

Tags: java, data-structures, enums, nested

Say I need a data structure in Java involving one set of categories, each with one set of subcategories. For example, let's say the main category is 'brand' (like, of a product) and the subcategory is 'product'. I want to be able to map the combination of brand+product to a piece of data e.g. a price.

I'd like to use an enum type for both 'brand' and 'product' if they were on their own, because

- Brand+product has only a small, single piece of data tied to it (the price)
- I need to refer to them many times throughout a reasonably large program, so the chance that I'll mistype any string literal keys I assign to them is basically one.

However, the number of brands/products is too large to have a *single* enum for each brand/product combination (around twenty brands each with ten products and a good chance of adding more later). I'd like to be able to use the structure like this:

```
    getPrice(APPLE.IPOD)

    getPrice(APPLE.MACBOOK)

    getPrice(HERSHEYS.PEANUT_BUTTER_CUPS)
```

Should I use some sort of nested enum? If so, how would that be implemented?

---

Bonus information: I've spent a bit of time googling 'java nested enum' but haven't come up with anything. The problem with structures like the first one in the ticked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424390/nesting-enums-in-java?rq=1) or thelosts's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636845/how-to-nest-an-enum-inside-the-value-of-an-enum?rq=1) is that I have too many categories all exhibiting the same behavior to write out very similar enum definitions so many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use an enum for this.

I would suggest you load this information from a file or database.  Java is not a good place for storing large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a getter and setter to the Brand enum that allows setting a Product enum, but that will not enforce that a Product is actually manufactured by that Brand. Besides, there is ever only one instance of each enum value -- so you could never have APPLE.IPOD and APPLE.IPAD. You either need a single enum type that represents the Cartesian product, or you need to load your values from a data store like Peter Lawrey suggests.